# Regular Expression in Javascript for finding parameters

Tags: javascript, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to write a regular expression in javascript to catch all named parameters in PostgreSQL string to put them in table

lets say we have

```
var query="SELECT table.data FROM table JOIN table2 ON table2.id=table.id_tab2 WHERE table2.field <> :parm1::int GROUP BY table.data HAVING table.data position(:docType::text in document_type) <> 0

var tab=new Array();

//
```

I need rs to put into tab all parameters: "`param1::int`" and "`docType::text`"
I tried do it myself but with no success :(
http://regexr.com?31nok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?  `:(\w+::\w+)`

Comment: I saw `-` and `_` in that character class, which `\w` won't match.  Are those characters allowed in postgres named parameters?

Comment: @Qsario: in what character class?  BTW, dash (`-`) is not allowed in postgresql typenames as far as i know, and underscore is matched by `\w`.  i don't see a problem here.

Comment: I was looking at his original character class in regexr.  And it appeared that `\w` wasn't matching `_` there, but I might just have been tired.

Answer (score 1):

and `(:[a-zA-Z0-9]+::[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: it amost what i wonted. Difference is, thay i need those parameters without : on begin tried with `:([a-z0-9_-]+::[a-z0-9_-]+)` ,but effect is the same

Answer (score 1):

There can be weird things between a-Z, so just use [a-z] with case insensitive or [a-zA-Z].  I think you probably want a global match (find all results).  Multi-line is something else, it makes `.` match `\n` which doesn't help you that I can see.  Try this:  http://regexr.com?31not

Answer (score 0):

when i try `:([^: ]+::[^: ]+)` and `(:[^: ]+::[^: ]+)` i see no difference- colon is in match in both casec.

However i found some other way

```
(?!:)([a-z0-9_-]+::[a-z0-9_-]+)
```

works perfectly.
first part `(?<=:)` determine "Matches a group before your main expression without including it in the result."

Thanks you all for your answers ;)